# What's the story/code behind StackExchange's tag storage and addition system?

Tags: discussion, xml, architecture, feed, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Does StackExchange use a tag-by-tag, XML-based feed of links to content for users, or is their system more complicated than that?  I think their system for organizing and delivering their content is very cool.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each site in the StackExchange network is backed by a SQL Server database.  This database stores all of the information about the site, including the posts, the votes, the users, the moderator flags, and the tags.

See also 
[Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369)

Comment: Oh.  That's interesting.  Thank you.  You see, when I was working with Drupal, some people recommended XML and some recommended SQL for storing tags.